# Error when comparing binary strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, binary

I have the following problem that is breaking my rspec test suite:

```
irb
2.4.1 :001 > "a\x01\x00\x00\x00l\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\a\x00\x00\x00"
=> "a\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000l\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\a\u0000\u0000\u0000"
2.4.1 :002 > "a\x01\x00\x00\x00l\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\a\x00\x00\x00" == "a\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000l\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\a\u0000\u0000\u0000"
=> true
```

Why does this comparison return false since they are the same strings?

1) Angle::Net::DataBuilder methods #private: data_to_bin convert [2**51 -1]
     Failure/Error: expect(answer).to eq "a\x01\x00\x00\x00l\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\a\x00\x00\x00"

```
   expected: "a\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000l\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\a\u0000\u0000\u0000"
        got: "a\x01\x00\x00\x00l\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\a\x00\x00\x00"
```

Comment: That comparison works in Ruby 2.3.3

Comment: I'm update the post. The comparasion works on IRB, it's wont work on RSPEC

Comment: Maybe you should [`force_encoding`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-force_encoding), `.force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT")`

Comment: This works, but why?

Comment: Maybe it was encoded differently, probably because https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6679

Comment: I was confused because the rest of the suite does not have to force the encoding, just in this specific case, and the IRB direct comparison is right, including using binding.pry and analyzing the data.

Comment: Yes, this happened is apparently correlated. Thanks, if you want to answer the question below I will mark you as an answer :)

Comment: When dealing with binary data, you have to ensure proper encoding. That data maybe be loaded from file, or streamed in a different encoding(UTF8, US-ASCII, etc). For text you can easily work that but not with data like these.

Comment: @MarlonHenrySchweigert which Ruby version do use it ?

Comment: Currently I use 2.4.1 @7urkm3n

Comment: Well, I have written an answer ;)

Comment: You _always_ have to ensure proper encoding, not just when dealing with binary data. Same bytes can have different meaning in different encodings, e.g. `0xC4` is `Ä` in ISO-8859-1 and `Ф` in ISO-8859-5. Therefore, `0xC4.chr('ISO-8859-1')` and `0xC4.chr('ISO-8859-5')` are not equal.

Answer (score 3):

Change definition of sting literal to force the encoding, `.force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT")`

Probably you can also do [`String#b`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-b)